# angulartics trigger event without event attributes

Tags: angularjs, angulartics

Is it possible to trigger GTM event without using `analytics-on="click" analytics-event="Download"`?

So I would like to add these tags over GTM interface or something so it's automatically added in GTM and Google Analytics.

I followed instructions here
https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-tag-manager
http://angulartics.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

With angulartics and angulartics-gtm, you can directly access the dataLayer using

> window.dataLayer

So just do a window.dataLayer.push() with your event in your angular code.

For example,

> ng-click="downloadClicked()"

Then you have downloadClicked function in angular controller to trigger a dataLayer push using window.dataLayer.push();